# Blank screenshot with WebDriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, java, page-objects

Im not sure why, but ever time my screenshot is executed, the images are saved as blank.
heres the code:

```
    public void screenshotOnError() throws IOException {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String ssTimestamp = String.valueOf(epoch);

    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("/Users/sqadan/Desktop/workFiles/maven/MavenProject/screenshots/" + ssTimestamp + ".jpg"));
    }
}
```

Here's the code that's calling this method:

```
    @Test
    public websiteProspector_beta doLogin(String myUsername, String myPassword) throws IOException {
    logs.InfoDetails("Logging into Tomcat8- 2092");

    try {
        username.sendKeys(myUsername);
        password.sendKeys(myPassword);
        loginButton.click();


        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getPageSource().contains(cF.homePage), true);
        logs.InfoDetails("Login successful");
    }catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        logs.errorDetails("Login unsuccessful");
        tU.screenshotOnError();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot function is creating a new WebDriver instance each time and then taking a screenshot of the default blank page in firefox.

You could try passing in your test's WebDriver instance so you get a picture from your test:

```
static public void screenShotOnError(WebDriver driver) {
    long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String ssTimestamp = String.valueOf(epoch);
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("/Users/sqadan/Desktop/workFiles/maven/MavenProject/screenshots/" + ssTimestamp + ".jpg"));
}
```

Then call it as:

```
tU.screenshotOnError(driver);
```